# Capture image and transfer it to another activity

Tags: java, android

I need help.
I have a project like Meme Generator, I have two Activities.
Activity_main (User Interface and has a button to trigger "choose camera option"
and Creatememe(as Second Activity to show the captured image from Activity_main).

Now my Problem is, When I'm using Android Version 4.0.4 to lower versions The image is passing through the Second Activity.
while using Android version higher that 4.0.4 the Image didn't pass to Second Activity, The image only shows inside Activity_main.
preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap) //<- shows image inside Activity_main.

Here are my codes for AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

Then here is my code for Activity_main

```
try {
    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    preview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b= preview.getDrawingCache();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateMeme.class);

    i.putExtra("Bitmap", b);
    startActivity(i);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then here's my code for Second Activity

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

on the OnClickListener of "choose camera option" use the next method

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Then,override `OnActivityResult` and handle the result like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CreateMeme.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

On your CreateMeme.class handle the extras like that -

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

For more information, Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: I got error on this line of intent.putExtra(extras); it says can't resolve method put.Extra(extras), so I've tried adding text as resource intent.putExtra("data",extras);
Still not working, It can't display the captured image even in MainActivity.

Comment: do intent.putExtras , with an S,my mistake..
I recommend that you read a little more of the basics before you continue..